# A verse similar to this

Tags: tanach, gifts

Is there a verse in the Tanakh that is similar to or contains some phrase similar to this phrase :

> "(G-d said) : This is our gift, so grant or withhold (restrict) without account (as you wish/like)"

The keywords here are Gift, Grant, withhold, account (reckoning). Any verse containing synonyms of those 4 words or something close to them or implying a similar meaning, can be considered similar verse. It doesn't necessarily have to be in the exact same order / structure. Perhaps this might add some context (but it is optional): in the Original source, these words are for Solomon or at least mentioned at the time when Solomon was alive.

The purposes of this question are just to know; only that.

An example I know of is a verse similar to the phrase "work in gratitude" in the Tanakh is something similar: "serve with gladness". Just to add context.

Comment: loosely, this overlaps with Psalms 84:11 sort of. Where is your quote from?

Comment: @רבותמחשבות It doesn't really matter where the sought idea came from if the sought idea is well-specified, which it is, here. However, Tomsofty33, this question would be a great deal more compelling if you'd include some information about why you expect that such a verse may exist in Tanach.

Comment: @Double AA the motivation for searching "a past reference" is to get more insight about its (the Quranic verse) actual meaning. But in this question I'm just asking for the reference and not the relation with the Quranic verse except only that it looks similar (Subjectively). No further explanation or knowledge of the Quran is needed to answer this. Is that explanation enough to motivate you ? Or is it me who is supposed to be motivated? What do you think would explaining this in the body of the question is gonna nullify the on hold status?

Answer (score 4):

**Deuteronomy 16:17:**

> אִ֖ישׁ כְּמַתְּנַ֣ת יָד֑וֹ כְּבִרְכַּ֛ת יְהוָ֥ה אֱלֹהֶ֖יךָ אֲשֶׁ֥ר
>   נָֽתַן־לָֽךְ׃

**Sefaria:**

> *But each with his own gift, according to the blessing that the LORD your God has bestowed upon you.*

**Aryeh Kaplan:**

> *Each person shall bring his hand-deliverd gift, depending on the
>   blessing that God your Lord grants you.*

This seems to me an adequate translation of the idea you presented.